# Understanding an Outer Automorphism of $S_6$

Tags: group-theory

In an [article (paper)](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/files/sixjan2308.pdf), there is a description of an outer automorphism of $S_6$. There are six pentagons, arranged with a rule, with vertices $1,2,3,4,5$. Any permutation of these vertices will permute the six pentagons, hence giving a map (homomorphism) from $S_5$ into $S_6$.

I understood this map as follows: if we interchange the vertices, the pentagons will be permuted. Consider permutation $(2 \,3)$, and its effect on the first pentagone **a** in the *note*.

(1) In **a**, vertices $2,3$ are not joined by a "continuous edge", hence after permuting $2,3$ there should not be continuous edge between $2,3$. Hence image of **a** after this permutation will be either **a,d** or **f** (am I correct?). Also, 5 is joined to both $2,3$ before permutation, hence after permuting $2,3$, vertex $5$ should be adjcent to them. We can conclude that **a** is mapped to **a** by permutation $(2\,3)$.

(2) The other way, in **a**, $2,3$ are not joined by continuous edge before permutation $(2\,3)$. Hence after permuting $2,3$, **a**  would be mapped into 
either **a,d** or **f**. Also, $4$ is joined to $2$ but not $3$ before permuting $2,3$; after permuting $2,3$, the vertex $4$ will be  joined to $3$ but not $2$; hence image of **a** by permutation $(2\,3)$ should be **d**.

I couldn't find my mistake in understanding, if any.

Can one explain the action of $S_5$ on the six pentagons in the article?

Comment: You've omitted an essential fact without which this is incomprehensible.  The point is that there are six ways to 2-color the vertices.  Without that, I don't see where your six pentagons come from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The crucial part you missed is "(up to choices of colors)" (in the third line of the section). If you distinguish between colours, there are twice as many pentagons. Applying $(23)$ to **a** yields **e** with colours swapped.

Comment: @jorki: OK; means, given a (ordered) 5-cycle on vertices $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, there is **unique pentagon** containing the 5-cycle. By permutation of vertices, these 5 cycles (and hence the pentagons) will be permuted; this will be the map (homomorphism) from $S_5$ to $S_6$; am I correct?

Comment: @user28017: Yes, correct!